# Spring AOP: Annotation pointcut not causing advice to execute

Tags: java, spring-aop

I am using Spring AOP (with AspectJ annotation style support) and want to execute code if a method is annotated with a specific annotation (`WsTransaction`).

Here is my aspect:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class ExampleAspect {

    @Pointcut("execution(* example.*.ws.*.*(..))")
    public void isWebService() {}

    @Pointcut("@annotation(example.common.ws.WsTransaction)")
    public void isAnnotated() {}

    @Before("isWebService() && isAnnotated()")
    public void before() {
        System.out.println("before called");
    }
}
```

This is an example class where I expect it to run:

```
package example.common.ws;

@Endpoint
public class SomeEndpoint {

    @WsTransaction() // I want advice to execute if this annotation present
    @PayloadRoot(localPart = "SomeRequest", namespace = "http://example/common/ws/")
    public SomeResponse methodToBeCalled(SomeRequest request) {
            // Do stuff
            return someResponse;
    }
}
```

When I change `@Before` to only use `isWebService()` it is called but when I try it with `isWebService() && isAnnotated()` or just `isAnnotated()` nothing seems to happen.

I have `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>` in my Spring config.

The endpoint is created by Spring (using `component-scan`).

The annotation's retention policy is runtime.

Spring version is `3.0.3.RELEASE`

I am not sure what is wrong or what I can try to debug.

Update: It seems Spring AOP doesn't pickup @Endpoint annotated classes

Update 2: `AopUtils.isAopProxy(this)` and `AopUtils.isCglibProxy(this)` are both `false` (Even when using `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly I had to use `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>` to use class-based (CGLIB) proxies (instead of Java interface-based proxies).

Secondly (and this is where I got stuck) I had to specify the above in the `contextConfigLocation` of the servlet handling the SOAP requests (`MessageDispatcherServlet`) instead of the root application context.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there may be some issue with the pointcut declaration.

```
  @Pointcut("@annotation(example.common.ws.WsTransaction)")
```

See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922561/aspectj-pointcut-with-annotation-parameters) for possible solution

Comment: I have tried specifying parameter name in the pointcut (`@Pointcut("@annotation(wsTransaction)")` and specifying the value and argNames) with no luck. Also according to http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html I should be able to use it like I did.

Comment: Pointcuts like that provided above worked fine for me in Spring as well with annotated methods.