# AspectJ - Get value of annotated method parameter

Tags: java, aspectj

I created custom annotation `@MyAnn`. And I will annotate method parameters with it.

For example: `public static call(@MyAnn String name){...}`

Using AspectJ, how can I access and update the values of all parameters annotated with the annotation?

I found some sample code showing how to create pointcuts targeting custom annotations, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922561/aspectj-pointcut-with-annotation-parameters).

So for now, I created an aspect with a pointcut.
But I don't know hot to get value of parameter annotated with `MyAnn`.

```
@Aspect
public class MyAnnAspect {

    @Around("execution(@my.package.test.MyAnn") // I hope this pointcut will work
    public void changeParameter(final ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        // How I can there get parameter value (and chage it)? 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't think that pointcut work, because it is not the method which is annotated, by the way you can do:

```
MethodSignature ms = (MethodSignature) pjp.getSignature();
Method m = ms.getMethod();
Annotation[][] pa = m.getParameterAnnotations();
```

Now you can iterate over the annotations, and find the proper annotation, if present get the parameter value by calling `pjp.getArgs()`.

Comment: How can you get the field name/field value from getArgs. ? It will give only all the values. There is no relation with the annotation.

Comment: why don't you write complete answer?