# Create AspectJ for annotation with Target=ElementType.TYPE (Class annotation)

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, aspect

I want to execute a simple log on all methods of annotated class with a custom annotation. I've created the next annotation:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface FooAnnotation {}
```

And it's used on a random class:

```
@FooAnnotation
public class Bar{
  ...
}
```

Of course my start class has @EnableAspectJAutoProxy annotation

```
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@SpringBootApplication
public class FooApplication {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(FooApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

In the related AspectJ I need to define a *@Pointcut* to execute *@After* on all methods of all clases that are annotated with *@FooAnnotation*

I tried the next AspectJ and it **doesn't work**

```
@Slf4j
@Aspect
@Component
public class FooAspectJ{

  @Pointcut("within(x.y.z.FooNotify)")
  private void annotatedWithin() {}

  @Pointcut("@within(x.y.z.FooNotify)")
  private void annotatedAtWithin() {}

  @Pointcut("@annotation(x.y.z.FooNotify)")
  private void annotatedAtAnnotation() {}


  @After("annotatedWithin() || annotatedAtWithin() || annotatedAtAnnotation()")
  private void afterAnnotation(JoinPoint joinPoint){
    log.info("Executed annotated {}", joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
  }

}
```

I see similar post about this, like
[@AspectJ pointcut for all methods of a class with specific annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011089/aspectj-pointcut-for-all-methods-of-a-class-with-specific-annotation) and [aspectj pointcut with annotation parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922561/aspectj-pointcut-with-annotation-parameters), with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like

```
@Pointcut("within(@x.y.z.FooNotify *)")
```

**Example:**

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@FooNotify
@Repository
public class Bar {
  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Bar.class);

  public String returnSomeString() {
    logger.info("returnSomeString ...");
    int i = returnMeAnInt();
    logger.info("returnMeAnInt returned {}", i);
    return "Hello";
  }

  public void doSomething() {
    logger.info("doSomething ...");
  }

  private int returnMeAnInt() {
    logger.info("returnMeAnInt ...");
    return 4;
  }
}
```

**Aspect:**

```
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.After;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Aspect
public class BarAspect {
  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BarAspect.class);

  @Pointcut("within(@FooNotify *)")
  public void fooNotifyPointcut() {}

  @After("fooNotifyPointcut()")
  public void afterAnnotation(JoinPoint jp) {
    logger.info("afterAnnotation joinpoint: {}", jp.getStaticPart().getSignature());
  }
}
```

**Annotation:**

```
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(TYPE)
public @interface FooNotify {}
```

**Call:**

```
 bar.returnSomeString();
    bar.doSomething();
```

**Logs:**

> Bar:13- returnSomeString ...
>
> Bar:24- returnMeAnInt ...
>
> Bar:15- returnMeAnInt returned 4
>
> BarAspect:21- afterAnnotation joinpoint: String
> com.pkg.Bar.returnSomeString()
>
> Bar:20- doSomething ...
>
> BarAspect:21- afterAnnotation joinpoint: void
> com.pkg.Bar.doSomething()

For private methods, you have to use full aspectj.

Comment: It doesn't work. My class annotated with @FooNotify on class, don't log when a inner method executed

Comment: Is your `@FooNotify public class Bar{..}` a spring component ?

Comment: Correct. It's a @Repository

Comment: It seems to be working fine for me..I'll post full example